# JPA ManyToOne in MappedSupperClass

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I am trying to create some basic abstraction for my JPA entities. I have a base abstract class `AbstractModel` which has `ID` and `Version`. I think have another Abstract class with extends `AbstractModel` adding some auditing columns. Then I have my actual entities representing tables. I have a `ManyToOne` mapping in `AbstractAuditModel` class but it doesn't seem to like it. Is is even possible to accomplish this in a `MappedSuperClass`?

My Code is below.

AbstractModel.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractModel implements Serializable {

    @Transient
    protected static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    @Version
    protected Long version;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getVersion() {
        return version;
    }

    public void setVersion(Long version) {
        this.version = version;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

AbstractAuditModel.java

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractAuditModel extends AbstractModel {

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_at", nullable = false)
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    protected Date lastModifiedAt;

    @CreatedBy
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "created_by")
    protected User createUser;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by")
    protected User modifyUser;

    public Date getCreatedAt() {
        return createdAt;
    }

    public void setCreatedAt(Date createdAt) {
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    public Date getLastModifiedAt() {
        return lastModifiedAt;
    }

    public void setLastModifiedAt(Date lastModifiedAt) {
        this.lastModifiedAt = lastModifiedAt;
    }

    public User getCreateUser() {
        return createUser;
    }

    public void setCreateUser(User createUser) {
        this.createUser = createUser;
    }

    public User getModifyUser() {
        return modifyUser;
    }

    public void setModifyUser(User modifyUser) {
        this.modifyUser = modifyUser;
    }

    @Override
    public abstract int hashCode();

    @Override
    public abstract boolean equals(Object obj);

    @Override
    public abstract String toString();
}
```

I am using those classes like this.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "item_snapshot", schema = "honda_ots")
public class ItemSnapshot extends AbstractAuditModel {

// code

}
```

The relevant stack trace is below.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: com.testapp.model.ItemSnapshot.modifyUser
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.getCollectionBinder(CollectionBinder.java:330) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processElementAnnotations(AnnotationBinder.java:1922) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.processIdPropertiesIfNotAlready(AnnotationBinder.java:963) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:796) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3845) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3799) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1412) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:852) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.8.Final.jar:4.3.8.Final]
    ... 66 common frames omitted
```

Comment: As the message says, your field "modifyUser" (of type User) cannot be a ManyToMany/OneToMany. It could be OneToOne or ManyToOne ... if User is en Entity. Not sure how much clearer it can be

Comment: Damn, I didn't catch the @ManyToMany, should have looked over my code more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want `@ManyToMany` you would have to make it a `List<User>` rather than `User`.  You might also need to add a `@JoinTable` in which to keep the relationship. Otherwise make it many to one, which would suit your name as `last_modified_by`

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here :

```
@LastModifiedBy
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by")
protected User modifyUser;
```

First you need `Set<User> modifiedBy` . Also when you want a `@ManyToMany` relation i think you have to specify the column, which will holds the relations.

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_model_modifications",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by",
referencedColumnName = "id"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "modified_model_id",
referencedColumnName = "id"))
Set<User> modifiedBy;
```